# Could not find a declaration file for module 'use-sound'

Tags: react-hooks, import

I ran `npm i use-sound` and it seems that my module in unknown.

This is the error message:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'use-sound'. 'c:/Users/Maor/Projects/FullStack-Spotify-Clone/spotify-clone/node_modules/use-sound/dist/use-sound.esm.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
There are types at 'c:/Users/Maor/Projects/FullStack-Spotify-Clone/spotify-clone/node_modules/use-sound/dist/index.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". 
The 'use-sound' library may need to update its package.json or typing.
```

This is my package.json file:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-slider": "^1.1.2",
    "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs": "^0.8.1",
    "@supabase/auth-helpers-react": "^0.4.2",
    "@supabase/auth-ui-react": "^0.4.5",
    "@supabase/auth-ui-shared": "^0.1.7",
    "next": "^13.5.5",
    "query-string": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.47.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "stripe": "^13.9.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "uniqid": "^5.4.0",
    "use-sound": "^4.0.1",
    "zustand": "^4.4.3"
},
```

Im trying to use this hook in my React component, but i cant because if the error i mentioned

```js
"use client";

import { Song } from "@/types";
import MediaItem from "./MediaItem";
import LikedButton from "./LikedButton";
import Slider from "./Slider";

import useSound from "use-sound";

import { BsPauseFill, BsPlayFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { AiFillStepBackward, AiFillStepForward } from "react-icons/ai";
import { HiSpeakerWave, HiSpeakerXMark } from "react-icons/hi2";
import usePLayer from "@/hooks/usePlayer";
import { useState } from "react";

interface PlayerContentProps {
  song: Song;
  songUrl: string;
}

const PlayerContent: React.FC<PlayerContentProps> = ({ song, songUrl }) => {
  const player = usePLayer();
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(1);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  const Icon = isPlaying ? BsPauseFill : BsPlayFill;
  const VolumeIcon = volume === 0 ? HiSpeakerXMark : HiSpeakerWave;

  const onPlayNext = () => {
    if (player.ids.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const currentIndex = player.ids.findIndex((id) => id === player.activeId);
    const nextSong = player.ids[currentIndex + 1];

    if (!nextSong) {
      return player.setId(player.ids[0]);
    }

    player.setId(nextSong);
  };

  const onPlayPrevious = () => {
    if (player.ids.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const currentIndex = player.ids.findIndex((id) => id === player.activeId);

    const previousSong = player.ids[currentIndex - 1];

    if (!previousSong) {
      return player.setId(player.ids[player.ids.length - 1]);
    }

    player.setId(previousSong);
  };

  const [play, { pause, sound }] = useSound(songUrl, {
    
    volume: volume,
    onPlay: () => setIsPlaying(true),
    onEnd: () => {
      setIsPlaying(false);
      onPlayNext();
    },
    onpause: () => setIsPlaying(false),
    format: ["mp3"],
  });
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I found on the Antonio's Discord Channel:

Create on the root of the project a file "global.d.ts".

And paste this:

```
declare module 'use-sound' {
  export default function useSound(sound: any, options?: any): any;
}
```